# Submit form and redirect to same form

Tags: 7, webforms, status-messages

I have contact webforms in all pages on footer including the front page template. I want the user to be redirected to the same page they are in and but the message that the form have been submitted should be visible.

How can i do that? Is there a built in method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that comes in mind is:

- Install Rules and Webform Rules
- Go to your webform and at form settings set Redirection location: No redirect (reload current page)
- Add a rule, when a webform is submitted to fire action "Show a message on the site".